# The resource was not found for UPDATE and PUT

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am coding an app for bulk updating titles in a Google Calendar

"TODO:" -> "DONE:"

I can get the events with `Events:List`
I can get a particular event with `Events:Get`

... however ... like a few others before with different use cases ... I cannot ... in the API Explorer ... `UPDATE` or `PATCH` a record ... just get a resource was not found in RED

1. Any ideas?
2. Is there a list of common error conditions?

Answer (score 0):

**Any ideas?**

- As far as I know, there is already an existing old issue related to your concern in [Google Calendar Help Fourum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/ixQnzHmWDSk). And based from the thread, it hasn't been totally fixed yet.

However, you can try the workaround given that worked for many and this is done by deleting the old event and add it again with the same link and add `?nocache` at the end, instead of updating it.

In addition to that, you can also try the suggested action given for [404: Not Found](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#404_not_found) which is by [Implementing exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff).

**Is there a list of common error conditions?**

- [Handle API Errors](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors) provides a reference of Calendar errors, with some guidance on how to handle them in your app.

I hope that helps. :)

Comment: I'll check this out.  Mucho appreciated.